# how can I load configuration for kubernetes using kubernetes-client. Google Cloud

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have TS application that uses kubernetes-client library to connect to kubernetes in Google Cloud.

```
import { KubeConfig, CoreV1Api } from "@kubernetes/client-node";
const kc = new KubeConfig();
kc.loadFromDefault();
const kbsCoreApi = kc.makeApiClient(CoreV1Api);
```

When running locally works great, but when I dockerize it, it does not work due to not knowing how to load configuration. I tried to create a config file and load it using "kc.loadFromFile('~/some/path')" instead but It seems that I am missing something it gives me a HTTP error. Here is my configuration file.

```
    {
  "kind": "Config",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "clusters": [
    {
      "name": "cluster1",
      "cluster": {
        "certificate-authority-data": "cert-data",
        "server": "https://128.1.1.2"
      }
    }
  ],
  "users": [
    {
      "name": "cluster1",
      "user": {
        "password": "myPassword",
        "usernmae": "myUsername"
      }
    }
  ],
  "contexts": [
    {
      "name": "cluster1",
      "context": {
        "cluster": "cluster1",
        "user": "cluster1"
      }
    }
  ],
  "current-context": "cluster1"
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `kc.loadFromCluster();` instead of the `kc.loadFromDefault();` used in your code.

See [in-cluster example](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/blob/master/examples/in-cluster.js)

When starting the client with the in-cluster authentication, it will use the [ServiceAccount token](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/tree/master/examples/in-cluster-client-configuration) on `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount`

Also make sure that this ServiceAccount has the RBAC permissions for the resource operations that your client code use. But you should be able to get proper error messages, unless.

Comment: Hi Jonas, I set up my app using kc.loadFromCluster(). But now I get "HttpError: HTTP request failed" error when calling API function:

await kbsCoreApi.listNamespacedPod(namespace).then((res: any) => { return res; });

Comment: can you get any more info about why it failed?

Comment: that is all get when I call function with try catch block.

try {
    const pods = await kbsCoreApi
      .listNamespacedPod(namespace)
      .then((res: any) => {
        return res;
      });

    return pods.body.items;
  } catch (error) {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
    console.log("err: " + error);
  }

Comment: Is the request sent or does it fail before?

Comment: It is sent then fails.

Comment: Hi Jonas, you have been super helpful. It was authorization issue, needed to create clusterrolebinding to bind my role (RBAC). that was it, I marked you answer as answered. thanks.

Comment: @GusG what RBAC did you set? I have the same problem.